# Not able to execute java program which executes Neo4j query in Command Line

Tags: java, netbeans, cmd, neo4j

We are trying to execute a program that runs a Neo4j Query.
Using NetBeans it executes sucessfully. But when we run it using cmd, it gives the following error -

```
C:\>java -jar "C:\Users\sourabh\Documents\NetBeansProjects\freeb2\dist\freeb2.ja
r"
org.neo4j.cypher.EntityNotFoundException: Node 1 not found
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.gdsimpl.GDSBackedQueryContext$$anon$1.g
etById(GDSBackedQueryContext.scala:80)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.gdsimpl.GDSBackedQueryContext$$anon$1.g
etById(GDSBackedQueryContext.scala:48)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.NodeByIdBuilder$$ano
nfun$org$neo4j$cypher$internal$executionplan$builders$NodeByIdBuilder$$f$1$1.app
ly(NodeByIdBuilder.scala:41)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.NodeByIdBuilder$$ano
nfun$org$neo4j$cypher$internal$executionplan$builders$NodeByIdBuilder$$f$1$1.app
ly(NodeByIdBuilder.scala:41)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.GetGraphElements$.or
g$neo4j$cypher$internal$executionplan$builders$GetGraphElements$$castElement$1(G
etGraphElements.scala:30)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.GetGraphElements$$an
onfun$getElements$3.apply(GetGraphElements.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.next(Iterator.scala:372)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$next$1.apply(Closi
ngIterator.scala:44)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.failIfThrows(ClosingIterato
r.scala:86)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.next(ClosingIterator.scala:
43)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.next(PipeExecutionResult.scala:1
59)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.next(PipeExecutionResult.scala:3
3)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala
:30)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult$$anon$1.next(PipeExecutionResult
.scala:75)
        at freeb2.Freeb2.main(Freeb2.java:308)
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable
 to commit transaction
        at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.finish(TopLevelTransaction.java:
137)
        at freeb2.Freeb2.main(Freeb2.java:620)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Failed to commit, transaction ro
lledback
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.rollbackCommit(TxManager.
java:565)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:349
)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionI
mpl.java:134)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.finish(TopLevelTransaction.java:
127)
        ... 1 more
```

This is our code-

```
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
  try
  {
      tx.success();
   engine = new ExecutionEngine( graphDb );// HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
String x = "start root = node(1) return root";
result = engine.execute( x );
^^^^^ Error due to this line
```

What we are basically doing is, building the program using NetBeans and executing the code with the command that it generates under - `To run this application from the command line without Ant, try: ...`.
Any help would  appreciated.

Comment: Check DB_PATH in command line environment against DB_PATH in NetBeans. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395072/error-while-retrieving-neo4j-node-data-through-java

Comment: @JasonC thanks a lot!!! It worked, when we used absolute paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with the DB_PATH as mentioned by Jason C in the comment section of the question.
It was fixed by using absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

What is says, **EntityNotFoundException: Node 1 not found**

You have to insert data in your graph first before you can query it.

See the [import page](http://neo4j.org/develop/import) on neo4j.org and Rik's Blog for examples on how to import data.

And please work through the [Neo4j online course](http://neo4j.org/learn/online_course) to give you a safe footing in cypher (e.g. using node-id's is not recommended)

Comment: We created our database(data exists) and we are able to successfully query it in NetBeans. We are not able to do so in cmd.